# ezdxf -- transform undefined EPSG 3395 latitude longitude decimal degrees coordinates to WCS coordinates to save revised DXF file

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, dxf, ezdxf

**UPDATE 26 December 2023**

The `DXF` file was created via the Export Project to DXF function in QGIS 3.34. Although the exported `DXF` was set to EPSG 3395, that designation is not set in the `dxf.coordinate_type`. The answer by mozman and the previously displayed code have been combined as the following:

```
import ezdxf
from ezdxf import transform
from ezdxf.math import Matrix44

CRS_TO_WCS = True

doc = ezdxf.readfile("tester.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()
geo_data = msp.get_geodata()


def wcs_to_crs(entities, m):
    transform.inplace(entities, m)

def crs_to_wcs(entities, m):
    m = m.copy()
    m.inverse()
    transform.inplace(entities, m)

if geo_data:
    # Get the transformation matrix and epsg code:
    m, epsg = geo_data.get_crs_transformation()
else:
    # Identity matrix for DXF files without a geo location reference:
    m = Matrix44()
    epsg = 3395

if geo_data:
    m, epsg = geo_data.get_crs_transformation()
    if CRS_TO_WCS:
        crs_to_wcs(msp)
    else:
        wcs_to_crs(msp)
else:
    print("No geo reference data available.")
```

The result is "No geo reference data available."

I will ask a separate question ([ezdxf - DXF - set CRS for DXF file internally or via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77716058/ezdxf-dxf-set-crs-for-dxf-file-internally-or-via-python)) to set the CRS value.

---

All entities in the tester `DXF` are either `TEXT` or `LWPOLYLINE`.

My goal is to transform all `LWPOLYLINE` and `TEXT` entities in all layers in the `DXF` recursively from EPSG 3395 (latitude longitude in decimal degrees) to `WCS` coordinates, and then save that revised `DXF` file as a new file.

In order to do so, should I use `crs_to_wcs` or `globe_to_map`? Is there a good example that shows the steps?

Below is the python code modified from the `ezdxf` documentation:

```
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.math import Matrix44
from ezdxf.addons import geo

doc = ezdxf.readfile("tester.dxf")

msp = doc.modelspace()

# Get the geo location information from the DXF file:
geo_data = msp.get_geodata()
if geo_data:
    # Get transformation matrix and epsg code:
    m, epsg = geo_data.get_crs_transformation()
else:
    # Identity matrix for DXF files without geo reference data:
    m = Matrix44()
    epsg = 3395
```

Answer (score 0):

The `geo` add-on implements the [`__geo_interface__`](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) and is not required here.

```py
import ezdxf
from ezdxf import transform

CRS_TO_WCS = True

doc = ezdxf.readfile("tester.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()
geo_data = msp.get_geodata()


def wcs_to_crs(entities, m):
    transform.inplace(entities, m)

def crs_to_wcs(entities, m):
    m = m.copy()
    m.inverse()
    transform.inplace(entities, m)

if geo_data:
    m, epsg = geo_data.get_crs_transformation()
    if CRS_TO_WCS:
        crs_to_wcs(msp)
    else:
        wcs_to_crs(msp)
else:
   print("No geo reference data available.")
```

Please read the docs for the [GEODATA](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/dxfobjects/geodata.html) entity to understand the limitations.

- works only for local grid (linear) transformation
- works only for known CRS configurations
- GEODATA version 1 is not really supported (no docs)