# ezdxf - DXF - set CRS for DXF file internally or via python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, dxf, ezdxf

I have a `DXF` file that was created via the Export Project to DXF function in QGIS 3.34. Although the exported `DXF` was set to EPSG 3395, that designation is not set in the `dxf.coordinate_type`.

Where is the XML information stored in the `DXF` file (refer to https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfobjects/geodata.html) to set the CRS to EPSG 3395 Or can the CRS be defined via python?

This question is a pre-cursor to [ezdxf -- transform undefined EPSG 3395 latitude longitude decimal degrees coordinates to WCS coordinates to save revised DXF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77709215/ezdxf-transform-undefined-epsg-3395-latitude-longitude-decimal-degrees-coordi).